# Como reiniciar o app quando é trazido do background?

Tags: android, android-activity

Preciso que meu app reinicie sempre que ele é trazido do background do SO, para que o usuário seja obrigado a fazer login novamente.

Tentei usar o `finishAffinity()` no meu `onPause()` da activity, o problema é que esse método é chamado também quando há uma transição entre `activities`, fazendo com que quando o `OnBackPressed` fosse chamado a aplicação se reiniciasse também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não havendo outra solução, use uma *flag* para indicar quando deve fazer o finish.

Segundo entendi isso apenas não deve acontecer quando retorna de uma Activity lançada por ela.

Declare a *flag* como atributo

```
Boolean canFinish = true;
```

Quando lançar a Activity

```
canFinish = false;
startActivity(....);
```

No método `onPause()`

```
if(canFinish){
    finishAffinity()
}else{
    canFinish = true;
}
```

Parto do principio que `finishAffinity()` faz o que você pretende e que deve ser feito no `onPause()`.